# Multisite Pull Recent Image Attachments from Blog ID

Tags: multisite, images, blog-id

I am creating a WordPress network and am looking for a way to pull recent images from the sub blogs, but I am having some trouble doing so.

What is the easiest way to make this happen?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please explain in detail what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`switch_to_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) to switch blog contexts to a specific blog ID. From there on it's all down to [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) of the `attachment` type. And switching back to the current context with [`restore_current_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog).

Something like this:

```
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order'=> 'ASC' );

foreach ( get_posts( $args ) as $attachment ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID );
}

restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: Worked very well and thank you for the direction.  To add uniformity to the images I used the additional parameters for wp_get_attachment_image(); to include the thumbnail size.